# DBUnit : Validate foreign key which was generated as an auto id for another table

Tags: unit-testing, dbunit

The thing is :

I have some data in an xml which is taken up by a running thread which reads the data and after executing some business logic persists that data in to two tables lets say table A and table B.

The way it is done is the tuple of table B contain a foreign key which happens to be the auto generated id for the entries in Table A. Since what I am testing is the correctness of the thread I have no control what might be the generated auto IDs for the entries in table A and the data which I want to validate must test the join correctness for the entries of table A and table B.

In the expected data set I have no way of providing the auto generated IDs and foreign key values since I am unaware of that. Is there a way to do this if DB unit provides facility where you simply replace the expected value by a variable and using that variable in the corresponding entry in the other table ?
Or there is any other way to do it ?
Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

Well what I figured out was to have the actual data received through DBUnit by specifying the exact SQL rather than picking up individual tables and then ignore the ID column in the result set so that all you will be left with is the name to name mapping attributes in the each row of the result set . In the end was a pretty trivial stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@ExpectedDatabase` to check the result, it's possible to specify the modifier `assertionMode = DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT_UNORDERED`.

Do not specify an id field in the result set data, it must ignore id in the comparison.